# Apache virtualhosts no longer working after update to 13.10

Tags: server, apache2, php, virtualhost

I updated my kubuntu to 13.10 today and my virtualhosts that worked perfectly before are no longer working.

the `s2ensite` and `a2dissite` commands claim "site xxxxxx does not exists" even the files are in sites-aviable and were in sites-enabled I tryed to remove them from sites-enabled and then enable them again, but still apache claims they would not exists.

Here is one of my virtualhosts. They are basically all like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName expsite.local

    DocumentRoot /var/www/expsite/htdocs
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/expsite/htdocs/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride FileInfo
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

#   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
#   <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
#       AllowOverride None
#       Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
#       Order allow,deny
#       Allow from all
#   </Directory>

        CustomLog /var/www/expsite/logs/access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/www/expsite/logs/error.log
        LogLevel warn

#    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
#    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
#        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
#        AllowOverride None
#        Order deny,allow
#        Deny from all
#        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
#    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The 000-default is working and I can enable and disable it.

Comment: You can see below for a more complete answer:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/362682/ubuntu-13-10-server-403-error-after-upgrading-to-apache2-4

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ubuntu 13.10 and variants have moved to Apache 2.4 and Apache 2.4 wants enabled virtual host config files to end in `.conf` by default.  See here:

http://lyemium.com/content/virtual-host-issues-when-upgrading-apache-22-24

I just renamed my vhost config files to end in `.conf` and everything worked!

Comment: This issue took hours on 2016 after an upgrade. Thanks