# 403 error after upgrading to apache2.4

Tags: apache2

After upgrading from Ubuntu 13.04 server, the www pages won't display themselves.

> Error 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I've changed access control saves from apache2.2 to apache2.4, but that didn't work. What else could I do?

Answer (score 60):

What happened is that the syntax of the configuration files in apache2.4 have changed.

<sup>Source: This has happened to me as well after I upgraded to 13.10</sup>

## conf.d files

All files that were in `/etc/apache2/conf.d` should be moved to `/etc/apache2/conf-available`.

They now work the same way `sites` and `mods` work. Just put your conf files in the `conf-available` folder and enable the one you want with `a2enconf <config-file-name>`.

#### Example:

I had a file `conf.d/httpd.conf` which had the ServerName directive.
To make that work, I had to move it to the `conf-available` directory and enable it manually.

```
sudo mv /etc/apache2/conf.d/httpd.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/httpd.conf
sudo a2enconf httpd
```

## sites files

Previously, files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` had no extension. For example `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`. Now a `.conf` extension is required.

#### Example:

If you had `/etc/apache2/sites-available/some-site`, in 13.04 you can just enable it using `sudo a2ensite some-site`. Now it will give you an error saying

> ERROR: Site some-site does not exist!

To fix this, append a `.conf` to all your config files in `sites-available`.
You can do the same in `sites-enabled`, or you can delete all the files and re-enable them each manually.
*I recommend doing them manually since you probably need to fix each VHost (next step).*

```
sudo find /etc/apache2/sites-available/ ! -iname '*.conf' -type f -exec mv '{}' '{}'.conf \;
```

if you decided to do them manually:

```
sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*
sudo a2ensite your-site-name
```

## Virtual Host directives:

### allow/deny vs Require

If you had the following:

```
<Directory /path/to/your/site/>
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

It should become:

```
<Directory /path/to/your/site/>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

For more info, check on the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992466/apache-permission-denied#comment16000102_11993187) by [DaveRandom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/889949/daverandom) on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11993187/535122) on Stack Overflow.

*Simply put, if you upgraded to apache2.4 and kept the old `httpd.conf` of apache2.2, allow directive should keep working fine. If you upgraded your `httpd.conf` (which I would suggest), you will get 403 errors until you change the `Order`/`Allow`/`Deny` directives to their equivalent `Require`.*

### Directory Options

If you had Directory options, note that they all have to be prepended with a `+` or `-` or none of them at all. A mix of both is not allowed:

#### Example:

This is allowed:

```
<Directory /path/to/your/site/>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

So is this (Note that these examples don't both do the same thing, the previous one disables the `MultiViews` option, the next one doesn't):

```
<Directory /path/to/your/site/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
</Directory>
```

This is no longer allowed:

```
<Directory /path/to/your/site/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

Last config option will throw the a syntax error saying:

> Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may.

## Restart apache

Once everything is done, you need to restart your apache server for the changes to take effect:

```
 sudo apache2ctl restart
```

---

You can find a detailed [upgrade guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) from 2.2 to 2.4 on the official documentation.

Comment: On my system, there's no `httpd.conf` file, or `conf.d` directory. But there's an `apache2.conf` file. I tried moving it to the the `conf-available` directory, and got the following error when I restarted apache2: *apache2: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: No such file or directory* - What could be the reason?

Comment: @AmalMurali The `httpd.conf` was just an example. It is possible that you won't have any config files in the `conf.d` directory, in that case, just skip that step. As for `apache2.conf`, it should not be moved into the `conf-available` directory. It is the main configuration file of apache, and its path should be /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and must not be changed.

Comment: Wow. This is practically the only lucid overview to be found anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: there is no `config.d` or `sites available` folder. see all config files here : http://imgur.com/WczXp3v

Comment: @diEcho this answer is not fully valid for a xampp installation. This is only for apache that was installed with `apt-get`.

Comment: Oh.:( Will you please help how to do with xampp. See my issue :http://superuser.com/questions/843147/https-redirect-to-virtual-host-directory-and-http-not-working

Comment: I still get permission denied

Comment: @EdwardBlack There could be another reason if you are still using the default virtual host as explain in the answers of the following question: [Apache virtualhosts no longer working after update to 13.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2)

Comment: I know I should refrain by posting this kind of comments, but I just can't, as you saved my nightsleep! ;) Loved this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the web sites are running on your Ubuntu server.

Check your httpd.conf to make sure your DocumentRoot setting is pointing to the right place.

Check the file permissions on the folder referenced by DocumentRoot can be read by the user which the webserver runs as.

Check you have an appropriate index.html/index.htm etc and that the webserver is not trying to do a directory listing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problems.

I could not get apache 2.4 to run unless I used 'Allow from All', this was annoying as I wanted to provide a clean break from versions < 2.4. After a lot of trial and error and much searching I spotted a reference to access_compat and realised that this was there just for compatibility. Although the apache documentation says that both can be used, it recommends that you should not.

I removed this module from the /etc/sysconfig/apache2 load file, this solved my problem immediately.

Regards
Liam

Answer (score -1):

I am serving files from a non-standard directory so to make the upgrade work I had to edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and add:

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

After this, and the recommended changes above, the 403 error went away.