# Anyone has a Decent Ubuntu 13.10 Apache 2.4 Multivhost setup?

Tags: 13.10, virtualhost, apache2.4

I am frustrated with the new format settings Apache 2.4.6 
Someone would have any easy way to set up an Apache multivhost using Ubuntu 13.10 ?

regards

Comment: There isn't lots of significant differences between configuration. I had an [answer here on askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/362682/ubuntu-13-10-server-403-error-after-upgrading-to-apache2-4/362992#362992) to detail the most common differences between the Apache 2.4 & 2.2 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I run [VirtualMin](http://www.virtualmin.com/) on Centos. Works great, can create and delete servers, SQL databases and has IP sharing. Creates a new user for each site you are hosting and puts all their web data into that directory. Real nice solution. Free version is what I use. BTW don't see the need to get the corporate unless I want to rent out SSH accounts.