# Projects in /var/www folder are not accessible?

Tags: server, 13.10, permissions, apache2, lenovo

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and come from Ubuntu 13.04.

First check **locahost**, It's work fine. **PhpMyAdmin** is also work fine. I look some related problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362682/ubuntu-13-10-server-403-error-after-upgrading-to-apache2-4). But some similarities with this answer and still I have problem when I write for-example `http://localhost/PHP_Work/` in a browser.

**Problem**

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /PHP_Work/ on this server.
```

Path of **PHP_Work** folder is : `/var/www/PHP_Work`

Following results of line write by using terminal:

**conf.d files**

`zeb@zeb-Lenovo-B570:/etc/apache2/conf.d$ ls`

Result:  empty folder

`zeb@zeb-Lenovo-B570:/etc/apache2/conf-available$ ls`

Result:

```
charset.conf            localized-error-pages.conf    security.conf
javascript-common.conf  other-vhosts-access-log.conf  serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

**Site File**

`zeb@zeb-Lenovo-B570:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ ls`

Result: `000-default.conf  default-ssl.conf`

Don't know how and what changes make in `virtual host directives`. Or what should I do to sort it out , any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Zeb, you can also find information about WWW in http://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777 (Apart from the marked duplicate question).

Comment: @LuisAlvarado I don't think the problem is directory permissions here. Instead it's an apache2.4 & Ubuntu 13.10 issue. http://askubuntu.com/questions/362682/403-error-after-upgrading-to-apache2-4/362992#362992