# Why Apache virtual hosts on Ubuntu 14.04 is not working?

Tags: server, apache2, 14.04, virtualhost, apache2.4

I installed Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 and it was working fine by `http://localhost/` address.
But when I tried to add a new virtual host, for example `http://bow.loc` and restart apache, new address was not available on `http://bow.loc` and available on `http://localhost`.

My configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.bow.loc
    ServerAlias bow.loc
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bow/web

    <Directory /var/www/html/bow>
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I get my site by `http://bow.loc`?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/a/362992/8698

Comment: Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940475/apache-virtual-host-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/29834601#29834601). Got similar problem and it turns out to be the problem with system DNS configuration.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I forgot to add host in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   bow.loc
```

I thought apache does it automatically.

Comment: I've not had to do that any time before on a server. I do it from the client for testing purposes all the time though.  Can you clarify what you are saying here?

Comment: @flickerfly What are you meant? I made my virtualhosts points to my local machine to handle them with installed `Apache` server

Comment: I forgot to add this as well! :P

Comment: Damn, I wasted one our on this on a Debian 8 VM! Thanks!!!

Comment: @lucaferrario haha, me either. Simple bugs difficult to reveal ;) You're welcome!

Answer (score 30):

Since Apache 2.4, each virtual host file should have the .conf extension.

You can rename each virtual host file to include the .conf extension:

```
mv /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf
```

Use the a2ensite command to add the virtual host:

```
a2ensite example.com.conf
```

And reload Apache:

```
service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Thanks! And after this actions I don't need manually modified the `/etc/hosts` file and add hosts to it? Does apache will write new hosts automatically?

Comment: Apache doesn't write new hosts automatically, you should write it manually.  CMIIW

Comment: So, my config is right, and problem in order that I forgot to add host in `/etc/hosts`

Comment: other way is to modify apache2.conf and remove the ".conf" extension from the "IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*" directive. I use website domains as file names, so I dislike the extra ".conf" requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I have been trying all these solutions offered..but sadly nothing worked!
Alas i edited

```
    /etc/hosts
```

to make entry

```
    127.0.1.1 example.com test.com
```

and it worked!!

(Sorry if I'm not talking much technically!)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a python script that will automate the apache virtual host creation steps ... this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ruvoYbSbIU) explains how, download/code on [GitHub](https://github.com/rakibtg/Apache-Virtual-Hosts-Creator)

Answer (score -3):

```
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

Need char '+' : +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Now = Require all granted

Comment: Please explain, where to put this and what it does. Don't just post commands or configuration artefacts. See [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: You only need to put a + or - before the various Options if you are using a - to exclude one. Otherwise, they are good to go. Required all granted is for Apache 2.4. The Order, Allow lines are a 2.2 syntax.