# Apache server virtual hosts not working

Tags: apache2

So I have updated to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from 12.04. The problem is that my existing virtual hosts are not working after the upgrade. And yes I have tried

```
sudo a2ensite test.dev
```

but it says:

```
ERROR: Site test.dev does not exist!
```

This is what I have in the 
`/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory

```
test.dev       mysite.dev      anothersite.dev
```

the content of test.dev is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName test.dev
    ServerAlias www.test.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
</VirtualHost>
```

and the hosts file

```
127.0.0.1     test.dev
127.0.0.1     www.test.dev
```

Comment: Although this question for 13.10, the same problem happens when upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/362682/ubuntu-13-10-server-403-error-after-upgrading-to-apache2-4/362992#362992

Answer (score 4, accepted):

14.04 upgrades your Apache to 2.4
From this version the config files need to have the .conf extensions, in your case:

test.dev.conf
mysite.dev.conf
 
anothersite.dev.conf

Just rename your files.
You may also need to include some new permissions for the directory

Here's a pretty good guide:
https://library.linode.com/web-servers/apache/2.2-2.4-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have been trying all these solutions offered..but sadly nothing worked! Alas i edited

```
/etc/hosts
```

to make entry

```
127.0.1.1 example.com test.com
```

and it worked!!

(Sorry if I'm not talking much technically!)