# Apache not including site (virtual host) config

Tags: apache2, configuration, virtualhost

I have added a config file to my `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and added a link to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. Yet if I restart my server and check with `apache2ctl -S`, I only get the virtualhost from 000-default.

```
root@ns00001:/etc/apache2/sites-available# apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   ns00001.ip-x.x.x.x.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

The file I have created in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` is `mydomain.eu` and contains the following text:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.mydomain.eu
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test

        <Directory /var/www/test/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride AuthConfig
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I go to test.mydomain.eu I get the apache default page (It works!). So this means the 000-default takes over. 
yes, I have restarted the apache2 service after changing the config.

Can someone help me with this, what am I forgetting?

Comment: What is the name of your config file and link ?

Comment: my config file is called `deviaene.eu` and the link has the same name. I use the same config on another server with the same operating system and it works fine.

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/362682/403-error-after-upgrading-to-apache2-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been solved.

Apparently, in the new version of Apache, all site configs should end in `.conf`. I did this and the problem was solved.

This behaviour is defined by the following directive within `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Comment: This is a common problem which is why I asked for the name of your config files, but I see you got it sorted.

Comment: You mean end in `.conf`, dont' you?

Answer (score 0):

Try do disable the default site by running:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Your test.domain.eu should point to the correct documentroot location.
 One more thing do you have enabled NameVirtualhost in /etc/apache2/ports.conf ?

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Comment: I have dissabled 000-default, but now the subdomain points to `/var/www`.
I do not have a NameVirtualHost in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, how do I add this?

Comment: simply paste that line above in the /etc/apache2/ports.conf file and restart apache2

Comment: It didn't work. and when I restarted apache2 it said the following: `AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/ports.conf:1
`

Comment: It seems you are running Apache 2.4 since that option works fine in Apache 2.2. What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: The test.mydomain.eu is some placeholder for a real domain or you defined it locally on /etc/hosts file ?

Comment: This is a placeholder for a real domain.