# Using Apache2 to set up a basic webpage

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, iptables

I am having a problem with a test page I set up for my website. The config file (index.html) looks like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to website.net!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Success! The website.net virtual host is working!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Which should display a page like this in my browser when I navigate to www.mywebsite.net

Welcome to website.net!

## Success!  The website.net virtual host is working!

However I get a 403 "forbidden" error when I navigate to the page. What am I missing? I have the directory installed on /var/www/mywebsite.net/public_html/index.html

I have the permissions of the /var/www directory set to 755 so that others can read and exicute it but it does not seem to be working. I also have port 80 open on my iptable. The server is a VPS server if that makes a difference however I have added a DNS record for the ip address.

Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE:
Here is my virtual host configuration file "mywebsite.net.conf"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
ServerAdmin webmaster@mywebsite.net
ServerName  www.mywebsite.net
ServerAlias mywebsite.net
# Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
DocumentRoot /home/myusername/public/mywebsite.net/public
# Log file locations
LogLevel warn
ErrorLog  /home/mysuername/public/mywebsite.net/log/error.log
CustomLog /home/myusername/public/mywebsite.net/log/access.log combined
<Directory /home/myusername/public/mywebsite.net/public>
Options Indexes ExecCGI Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What are the ownership and permissions of "index.html" , where is it located, and what version of ubuntu / apache are you using ? the default location was recently changed from /var/www to /var/www/html

Comment: I am using apache 2.4.7(latest version). "index.html" is located at /var/www/mywebsite.net/public_html

The permissions are :drwxr-xr-x 3  755 root 4096

Comment: Try moving `index.html` to `/var/www/html/`.

Comment: This is a permissions problem. Check the permissions of the index.html file and all the parent directories. Also check your apache configuration and DocumentRoot

Comment: @saiarcot8as that would be a 404 error, file not found

Comment: I looked at my apache config file and the document root is /home/myusername/public/mywebsite.net
The parent directories before "index.html" are all have a permission value of 755. the permissions for "index.html" itself are 161.

Comment: Can you post the content of you virtual host configuration file? Although the permissions on the directory is `755`, what are the permission of the `index.html` file? Is there an `.htaccess` file inside the your directory which might have some configuration that forbids access on the directory?

Comment: There is no .htaccess file in any of the directories /var /www /public_html /mywbsite.net (I checked them one by one until I got to my index.html file)
This is the permission for the "index.html" file: "-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 161 May 27 21:21 index.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your virtual host file has a `.conf` extension, then I guess you are using 13.04 or 14.04, or maybe you just updated apache to apache 2.4.

In your case, you need to remove the following two directives:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
```

and replace them with the following directive

```
Require all granted
```

For a more detailed info, please look at my other answer which explains [what needs to be changed after upgrading apache2.2 to apache2.4](https://askubuntu.com/a/362992/8698).

Comment: Okay Thank you! That got rid of the 403 error but now it only displays a blank index. It gives me an "index of /" page but there are no sub directories to choose from. I tried adding my "index.html" do the document root and that finally worked correctly thank you!! Additionally yes I am using both Ubuntu 14.04 and apache 2.4.7

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run apache under your user

first edit /etc/apache2/envvars and look for

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

change www-data to your user, restart apache2 after that, let me know if it work