# Error while attempting to install Apache 2 version 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache2

I am attempting to install Apache2 version 2.2 on a computer I just upgraded from Ubuntu  12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS because a critical software package that runs perfectly on the version of Apache in 12.04 does not work on version 14.04.

From other questions in this forum, I see there is a way to specify a version number while using apt-get, but this isn't working. Here's what I get:

```
christopher@TRICIA:~$ sudo apt-get install apache2=2.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.2' for 'apache2' was not found
christopher@TRICIA:~$
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax to do this?

Comment: Version 2.2 is simply not available in the official repositories for Ubuntu 14.04. As far as I can tell, there are no PPAs either. There was a question asking the same thing a couple of days ago. If you really want 2.2, you'll have to use 12.04 or compile from source.

Comment: Personally, I prefer using the latest software which is, in general, less buggy and more secure. That aside, check out this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/362682/403-error-after-upgrading-to-apache2-4/362992#362992 to fix most of the problems which might arise after upgrading to apache2.4 and this question might be helpful as well http://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2

Comment: Here's the other one, in case that one ever gets an answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/483844/cant-install-apache2-2-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thanks, all. I would definitely prefer to use the latest version of Apache, but the package specifically references the Apache configuration file that was re-named in the current version. I will try compiling from source. Much appreciated!

Comment: I met same problem while moving website to another server

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/483844/cant-install-apache2-2-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because this version is not available on repository which you are using.

you can check which versions are available in repository
`apt-cache showpkg <pachagename>`
e.g. `apt-cache showpkg apache2`

then you can install that version using command
`apt-get install <packagename>=<complete version name>`
e.g. `apt-get install apache2=2.2.14-5ubuntu8.7`

Answer (score 0):

To install apache2.2 use the following process:

On a later distro (e.g. 16.04), I downloaded the 2.2.31 from the Apache site.

I built it using the following configuration:

```
./configure --enable-so --enable-ssl --with-included-apr --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-load-all-modules --enable-rewrite --enable-proxy --enable-proxy_connect --enable-proxy_http --enable-proxy_ajp --enable-authn_alias --with-npm=prefork --enable-proxy_balancer --enable-proxy_ftp --enable-cache --enable-suexec --enable-disk_cache  > conf.txt
```

Then of course tweaking the httpd.conf and ssl.conf files.

After that I just run the ./httpd -k start

And it works !

note that I added the apache2.4 via apt-get but never removed it. This means that after system start, I need to kill the apache2 process. And then I am able to start apache2.2. I had to install apache2.4 to use apachectl but later disbanded that because I use ./httpd